# webpack improve automation via improving dockerfile

Tags: docker, npm, webpack, docker-compose, dockerfile

I run want to know how to automate my npm project better with docker.
I'm using webpack with a Vue.js project. When I run `npm run buld` I get a output folder `./dist` this is fine. If I then build a docker image via `docker build -t projectname .` and run this container all is working perfectly.

This is my Dockerfile (found [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/))

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./dist /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

But it would be nice if I could just build the docker image and not have to build the project manually via `npm run build`. Do you understand my problem?
What could be possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing all of your work (`npm build` and others) outside of the container, and have infrequent changes you could use a simple shell script to wrap the two commands.

If you're doing more frequent iterative development you might consider using a task runner (grunt maybe?) as a container service (or running it locally).

If you want to do the task running/building inside of Docker, you might look at `docker-compose`. The exact details of how to set this would would require more detail about your workflow, but `docker-compose` makes it relatively easy to define & link multiple services in a single file, and start and stop them with a simple set of commands.